# Insecure versions of crypt hashes

Tags: hash, bcrypt, software

I read at [crackstation](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#faq) not to use these variants of bcrypt* ($1$, $2$, $2a$, $2x$, $3$),but  I've used [bcrypt ($2a$)](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/)  in various sensitive implementations recently.
Can any security expert clarify why recommending ($2y$, $5$, $6$) instead of ($1$, $2$, $2a$, $2x$, $3$), what is the original version proposed by Niels Provos, and in what they differ

---

*bcrypt is a key derivation function for passwords designed by Niels Provos and David Mazières, based on the Blowfish cipher, and presented at USENIX in 1999. Besides incorporating a salt to protect against rainbow table attacks, bcrypt is an adaptive function: over time, the iteration count can be increased to make it slower, so it remains resistant to brute-force search attacks even with increasing computation power.*

Comment: *I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment so I have to put this as an answer.* >Read this, please: php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php. $2a$ is secure in PHP>=5.3.7 – Andrey Botalov Sep 26 '12 at 12:36 [Serious crypto bug in php 5.3.7](https://threatpost.com/en_us/blogs/serious-crypto-bug-found-php-537-082211) [PHP 5.3.8 Fixes Serious Crypt Bug](http://news.softpedia.com/news/PHP-5-3-8-Fixes-Serious-Crypt-Bug-218487.shtml)

Comment: There is a fairly comprehensive presentation about the history of (most) password hashes, and some future directions at: http://www.openwall.com/presentations/Passwords12-The-Future-Of-Hashing/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- 2 - the original BCrypt, which has been deprecated because of a security issue a long time before BCrypt became popular.
- 2a - the official BCrypt algorithm and a [insecure implementation](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2011/q2/632) in crypt_blowfish
- 2x - suggested for hashes created by the insecure algorithm for compatibility
- 2y - suggested new marker for the fixed crypt_blowfish

So 2a hashes created by the original algorithm or the java port are fine, and identical to 2y-hashes created by crypt_blowfish. But 2a hashes created by crypt_blowfish are insecure.

- 5 is sha256crypt
- 6 is sha512crypt

The shaXXXcrypt algorithm are inspired by bcrypt but use sha2 instead of blowfish as hash functions in order to satisfy compliance requirements in the USA.

Comment: can you further explain what you mean by insecure implementation, and in what area they are particularly insecure ?

Comment: @sarepta, if the password contains characters outside the 7-bit range, some character are ignored. I added a link to the report, which explains it in detail.

Comment: can you (if possible) provide a link to download secure implementation ($2y$, $5$, $6$) in .net, it seems as if all the libraries in the web are $2a$ and its getting in my nerves!

Comment: Read this, please: http://php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php. $2a$ is secure in PHP>=5.3.7

Comment: @HendrikBrummermann can you comment further on how `$6` would work in bcrypt for password hashing, vs. `$2y$`?

Comment: @Shackrock `$6` is Sha512Crypt. That is an algorithm that is similar to BCrypt, but different. Most notably, it is based on Sha512 instead of Blowfish.

Answer (score 14):

## BCrypt variants

- **`$2$`**

  The original specification used the prefix $2$. This was in contrast to the other algorithm prefixes:

  - **`$1$`** - MD5
  - **`$5$`** - SHA-256
  - **`$6$`** - SHA-512
- **`$2a$`**

  The original specification did not define how to handle non-ASCII character, or how to handle a null terminator. The specification was revised to specify that when hashing strings:

  - the string must be UTF-8 encoded
  - the null terminator must be included
- **`$2x$`**, **`$2y$`** *(June 2011)*

  A bug was discovered in [crypt_blowfish](https://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_Blowfish), a PHP implementation of BCrypt.

  It was mis-handling characters with the 8th bit set. They suggested that system administrators update their existing password databases, replacing **`$2a$`** with **`$2x$`**, to indicate that those hashes are bad (and need to use the old broken algorithm).

  They also suggested the idea of having **crypt_blowfish** emit **`$2y$`** for hashes generated by the fixed algorithm. Nobody else, including canonical OpenBSD, adopted the idea of `2x`/`2y`. This version marker was was limited to crypt_blowfish

  http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2011/q2/632
- **`$2b$`** *(February 2014)*

  A bug was discovered in the OpenBSD implemenation of bcrypt.

  They were storing the length of their strings in an unsigned char. If a password was longer than 255 characters, it would overflow and wrap at 255.

  BCrypt was created for OpenBSD. So when they had a bug in *their* library, they decided it was ok to bump the version. This means that everyone else needs to follow suit if you want to remain current to "their" specification.

  http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20140224132743
  http://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=139320023202696